# Convert aspect to native AspectJ notation

Tags: java, reflection, aspectj, aspect, aspects

I have this aspect:

```java
public privileged aspect Teste {
private ISupermarket supermarket;

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* ca1.business.SupermarketFactory.createSupermarket(..))", returning = "result")
    public void afterCreateSupermarket(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        supermarket = (ISupermarket) result;
    }
}
```

The thing is that I want to code it in native AspectJ notation.

I searched but the closest I got was to this:

```java
void after() returning(result) : pointcut(* ca1.business.SupermarketFactory.createSupermarket(..)) {
    supermarket = (ISupermarket) result;
}
```

But this gives me some errors because it is not well coded.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the answer:

```java
pointcut afterCreateSupermarket():
    call(ISupermarket ca1.business.SupermarketFactory.createSupermarket(..));

after() returning(Object result): afterCreateSupermarket() {
    supermarket = (ISupermarket) result;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `after() returning(Object ISupermarket)` and get rid of the cast?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the cast and the named pointcut, you can also do this:

```java
after() returning(ISupermarket result) : call(ISupermarket ca1.business.SupermarketFactory.createSupermarket(..)) {
    supermarket = result;
}
```